# Comparing motorsport lap times for different makes of car

Tags: nonparametric, median

My task is to compare sets of lap times for two different makes of racing car at a given circuit, set by different groups of competent drivers (being competent eliminates very slow outliers). The lap times are measured down to 1/1000 second, so are essentially continuous. The goal is to be able to say that "Car 1 is on average x seconds faster per lap than Car 2", bearing in mind that by "on average", I mean that most of the time, the same driver will be x seconds faster in Car 1 than Car 2, were he to drive both cars. Some drivers will be faster in Car 1; others will be faster in Car 2.

The sample sizes of lap times in each car are different and quite variable, and can range from very small (say, 5), to 100. Some drivers contribute to only 1 of the sets of times; some drivers will have times in both sets.

The distributions in each set of lap times are broadly linear, i.e. the lap times increase approximately linearly from fastest to slowest.

How would I best go about comparing the two sets representing two cars to arrive at a difference in seconds? I don't just want to compare the two samples; I want a numerical difference. The approach I am taking so far is to simply compare the medians of the two sets to arrive at a numerical difference by subtracting the medians. Is that reasonable?